# Content Query web part Rendering HTML source

Tags: sharepoint-2010, publishing, cqwp

We are using a Content Query web part  to query for a specific reusable HTML content item and display it in a page layout (so it exists on every page) but it is appearing as HTML source, not rendered HTML. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

For me I had to do the reverse, and enable output escaping.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to customise the ItemStyle.xsl file (ie: by creating a copy and adding your own style) which prints out the content - and specify `disable-output-escaping="no"`.

Like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="@Value" disable-output-escaping="no" />
```

Here's how to customise the ItemStyle: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx